# Change structure multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

Good day. I am new at php and I have a small problem. I have an array.. I want to change stucture of it .. **object_type** sometimes the same.. I want to have multidimensional array with **object_type** a key and value all arrays with this object_type.

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [initiator_id] => 259
        [object_type] => 1
        [object_id] => 905
        [date] => 2021-11-16 06:24:16
  
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [initiator_id] => 259
        [object_type] => 1
        [object_id] => 905
        [date] => 2021-11-16 04:54:54
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [initiator_id] => 259
        [object_type] => 1
        [object_id] => 905
        [date] => 2021-11-16 04:53:58
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [initiator_id] => 219
        [object_type] => 2
        [object_id] => 915
        [date] => 2021-11-16 04:53:58
    )
```

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Have a look at this topic: [How can I create an array from the values of another array's key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550976/how-can-i-create-an-array-from-the-values-of-another-arrays-key). Does this help you along?

Comment: Lvn W, yes .. I tried several times.. it did not help...

Comment: something like [this](https://3v4l.org/uAtBJ) might help.

Comment: berend, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find how to create `Multidimensional Arrays`. Click here [PHP Multidimensional Arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multidimensional.asp)

And to learn PHP language [www.w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/php/) is a very good site. You can find almost every example briefly explained here.

I hope this example may solve your issue.

```
<?php

$obj = array("initiator_id"=>"35", "object_type"=>"37", "object_id"=>"43");
$obj_2 = array("initiator_id"=>"135", "object_type"=>"237", "object_id"=>"343");

$array_list = array (
          array("Test 1",22,18),          
          array("Test 2",5,2),
          array("Test 3",17,15)
        );
        
$array_list[1]["new"] = $obj_2; 
  
        
$result = array_merge($array_list, $obj);      
    
  echo "<Pre>";
  print_r($result);
  echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test 1
            [1] => 22
            [2] => 18
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test 2
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 2
            [new] => Array
                (
                    [initiator_id] => 135
                    [object_type] => 237
                    [object_id] => 343
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test 3
            [1] => 17
            [2] => 15
        )

    [initiator_id] => 35
    [object_type] => 37
    [object_id] => 43
)
```

Comment: If you have the answer for the provided example, please share exact code snippet or at least describe the algorithm that will solve it. Adding links for generic documentation is not really helpful.

Comment: @AlexG I just edit the Answer. is this example helpful?

Comment: I think what you said, is perfectly valid, and shows how to manipulate arrays in a multi-dimensional way, but the question was quite vague, and I'm not sure that's what he meant.  From what I can infer he was asking about the key type, and implying it could be an object, which is nonsense.  What you put, implies a sensible question, which this was not.  Good job for trying to rationalise the irrational though.