# How to change array format in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have simple question:

How to change this array

```
Array ( [0] => taxonomy-term-1 [1] => taxonomy-term-2 [2] => taxonomy-term-3 )
```

to this array?

```
array( 'taxonomy-term-1', 'taxonomy-term-2', 'taxonomy-term-3' )
```

---

Why I am asking for that:

```
$slugs = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'ml_patternsCustomTaxonomy',['fields'=>'slugs']);
```

returns

```
Array ( [0] => taxonomy-term-1 [1] => taxonomy-term-2 [2] => taxonomy-term-3 )
```

but

```
array(
    'title'       => $title,    
    'content'     => trim($patternContent),
    'categories'  => $slugs
)
```

doesn't work, and

```
//
'categories'  => array( 'taxonomy-term-1', 'taxonomy-term-2', 'taxonomy-term-3' ),
```

works.

Why?

Comment: [They're the same.](https://3v4l.org/pRTVS#v8.1rc3) An associative array that's keyed with 0-based consecutive non-negative integers is the same as an indexed array.

Comment: I've updated my post, if u can look at this :)

Comment: do you want something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550976/how-can-i-create-an-array-from-the-values-of-another-arrays-key